# jQuery - adding elements into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to add the ID's, which are the $hexcode values from the html span into an array. How do I do this with jQuery? Eventually, I'm going to need to grab these hexcode values and match them to a color index.

```
<?php
// display every color in the world

$r = 0;
$g = 0;
$b = 0;
$i = 0;
$step = 16;

for($b = 0; $b < 255; $b+=$step ) {
    for($g = 0; $g < 255; $g+=$step) {
        for($r = 0; $r < 255; $r+=$step) {
        $hexcolor = str_pad(dechex($r), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($g), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).str_pad(dechex($b), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo '<span class="color_cell" id="'.$hexcolor.'" style="width: 5px; height: 5px; background-color:#'.$hexcolor.'; border: 1px dotted;">&nbsp;</span>'

        if($i%256 == 0) {
            echo "<br />";
        }
        $i++;
        }
    }

}
?> 
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ids = [];

    $(document).ready(function($) {    
    $(".color_cell").bind('click', function() {
        alert('Test');
        //how do i add the ID (which is the $hexcolor into this array ids[]?
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));       
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks alright to me. What's not working?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? What is not working?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this, at the end of the each loop, ids array will contain all the hexcodes.

```
var ids = [];

    $(document).ready(function($) {
    var $div = $("<div id='hexCodes'></div>").appendTo(document.body), code;
    $(".color_cell").each(function() {
        code = $(this).attr('id');
        ids.push(code);
        $div.append(code + "<br />");
    });



});
```

Comment: Thanks! What is an easy way to check/print my array?

Comment: console.log(ids) if you are in Chrome or Firebug on Firefox will log it to the developer console.

Comment: var divnew = document.createElement('div');
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    divnew.innerHTML += ids[i] + '<br/>';
}
$('body').append(divnew);

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = [];

    $(document).ready(function($) {    
    $(".color_cell").bind('click', function() {
        alert('Test');

        ids.push(this.id);       
    });
});
```